# SFML cursor seems broken in linux

Tags: c++, sfml, text-cursor

So, i have a cursor sprite:
[image: cursor sprite]
I load this sprite with:

```cpp
sf::Cursor cur;
sf::Image cur_default;
if(!cur_default.loadFromFile("assets/sprites/cursors/cursor_default.png"))
{
    std::cerr << "ERROR: unable to load file 'assets/sprites/cursors/cursor_default.png'\n";
    return -1;
}
cur.loadFromPixels(cur_default.getPixelsPtr(), cur_default.getSize(), cur_default.getSize() / 2U);
```

When i was testing my code, I realized that the left size of the sprite was white, and that the colors didn't show up (replaced the white/gray with blue). After resizing the image to 32x32 pixels, it seems as if there are random while lines in my cursor. Unfortunately, I could not take a screenshot of the behavior because it wasn't showing up. I'm aware that according to the SFML wiki:

> On Unix, the pixels are mapped into a monochrome bitmap: pixels with an alpha channel to 0 are transparent, black if the RGB channel are close to zero, and white otherwise.

However, it states *unix* not *unix like*, so I assume that is not the case for linux, but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. I'm confused on why there are random white lines in my sprite, and how to fix it (AND also why the colors are not working correctly).

Comment: On stack overflow people tend to ask questions. What kind of question are you asking? I mean, I as potential person who could try to help you would like to see direct question with good description to know what you are asking about. Are you asking if what you are doing is correct? If monochrome bitmap mapping is exclusive for unix? Are you looking for reason why white lines in your cursor appears?

Comment: @Advent ah sorry. I fixed it

Comment: Are you scaling the image or using a zoomed view when drawing the cursor?

Comment: @Miguel no, i am not